# I've converted a hash to an array, what is the proper method to use this array in a class now?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd like to use this array with a class called IP_data, but I'm appending with `push` and not using the key, and value pair like I'd like to. What is the proper method to use to accomplish this task?

I'm getting this

```
[["172.31.251.13", 12], #<IP_DATA:0X007FCD5D1BE630 @IP=[0], @COUNT=[1]>]
```

I would like to get this

```
[#<IP_DATA:0X007FCD5D1BE630 @IP=[172.31.251.13], @COUNT=[12]>]
```

Here is the code

```
# Begin lookups for tgt addresses
target_ip_data = Array.new
@tgt_ip_array = Array.new
@events.each do |ip_event|
  def get_target_ip(sid,cid)
    IpsIpHdr.where('sid =? and cid =?', sid, cid).first.ip_dst
  end
  tgt_ip = get_target_ip(ip_event.sid, ip_event.cid).to_s(16).rjust(8,'0').scan(/.{2}/).map(&:hex).join('.')
  target_ip_data.push(tgt_ip)
  tgt_ip_hash = Hash[target_ip_data.group_by {|x| x}.map {|k,v| [k,v.count]}]
  @tgt_ip_array = tgt_ip_hash.to_a
  @tgt_ip_array.push(IP_data.new([0],[1]))
end
# End lookups for tgt addresses
```

If it helps, here is the class.

```
class IP_data
  attr_accessor :ip, :count

  def initialize(ip, count)
    @ip = ip
    @count = count
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to understand what's difficult here:

```
class IpData < OpenStruct
end

a = [["172.31.251.13", 12]]

> IpData.new(ip: a[0].first, count: a[0].second)
=> #<IpData ip="172.31.251.13", count=12>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@events.each do |ip_event|

  ...
  ...

  tmp = tgt_ip_hash.to_a # and not @tgt_ip_array = tgt_ip_hash.to_a
  @tgt_ip_array.push(IP_data.new(tmp.first,tmp.last))
end
```